# How to automatically determine filetype by first line in file using vim?

Tags: vim, runtime, filetype

My vim can determine filetype by first line of file (e.g. #!/bin/bash). But check of first line occurs only at the start of vim. How to do runtime checking of this?

Comment: Runtime of _what_? "check...occurs only at the start of vim" -- this is the runtime of vim. Do you mean the runtime of the script? In that case, the check occurs when you try to execute the script, and the system determines which program to use to run it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it occurs when the file is first loaded, not when Vim itself loads, which wouldn't be very useful.  To re-trigger this detection for the current buffer:

```
:filetype detect
```